# Rails add variable to another variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a bit stuck. And I know there should be an easy solution. 
So I have this line of code:

```
  <% if $current_course.claimedreward1 == false%>
```

and a variable

```
$number = 1
```

I am trying to get the 1 replaced by $number

I tried

```
<% if $current_course.claimedreward+$number == false%>
```

There must be a super simple way to do this. I found #{} but it only seems to work for strings. I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to build a method/attribute name programatically:

```
<% if $current_course.send("claimedreward#{$number}") == false%>

update_attribute("claimedreward#{$number}", true)
update_attributes("claimedreward#{$number}" => true)
```

Comment: what if I want to set it, for example



     <% $current_course.update_attributes(claimedreward1: true) %>

Comment: @M1xelated Updated answer.